# Enlarge an image from zero to full size on image load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm placing images of a bubble randomly and I want to simulate the effect of making the bubble by enlarging the image from zero to full size. I'm using CSS `transform:scale();` but I want to trigger the animation when the image loads.

Comment: Hi, why not using CSS animation `transform:scale();` ?

Comment: ^^ Definitely use CSS.  jQuery animation has the potential to look choppy on some browsers, whereas a CSS transition will use the browser's native rendering techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a class to the image when it finishes loading, and specify proper `transition` and `transform` rules in CSS.

```js
$("img").load(function() {
  $(this).addClass("loaded");
});
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform 1s;
  transform: scaleX(0) scaleY(0);
}
img.loaded {
  transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://placekitten.com/600/600/">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways which doesn't require jQuery.

This way is preferable:

```js
var pics = document.querySelectorAll(".zoom");
for (var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
    pics[i].addEventListener('load', function() {
      this.classList.add("loaded");
    }, false);
}
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: scale(0,0);  
}
img.loaded {
  transform: scale(1,1);  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/00f/fff?text=Dummy-Image" class="zoom">
```

and this could be used when the amount of images is limited:

```js
function imgresize(el) {
  el.classList.add("loaded");
}
```

```css
img {
  transition: transform .5s;
  transform: scale(0,0);  
}
img.loaded {
  transform: scale(1,1);  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x200/00f/fff?text=Dummy-Image" onload="imgresize(this);">
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try `onload()` function to do certain tasks that only happend when something is loaded.

i.e;

```
$('img').on('load',function(){
   alert('image loaded');
}
```